# PowerShell recursively parse all report files in a folder and write to Excel

Tags: powershell, parsing

I have a folder with multiple report files that I need to parse unique lines and segments and then write to an Excel file.

Report folder example:
\Path\Report\1.ctx
\Path\Report\2.ctx
\Path\Report\3.ctx
.
.
.

Each report file has the same format.

I need to grab data from lines 11, 16 and 17.

Each of these lines has a unique format.  I parse each line based upon it's unique criteria and then write that to the last row and specified column of an Excel.

I don't know how to do this recursively for all report files in the folder.

I have the following working code which processes one named file and writes the data out.

Any and all suggestions are appreciated.

```
#Get Data
#Gets the line with the Date
$FileDateLine = (Get-Content \\Path\Report\1.ctx | select -Index 11) 

#Gets the line with the Name
$FileLine = (Get-Content \\Path\Report\1.ctx | select -Index 16) 

#Gets the line with the count
$FileDocCountLine = (Get-Content \\Path\Report\1.ctx | select -Index 17) 


#Open Excel and parse each variable into specific cells
$Excel = New-Object -comobject Excel.Application
$Excel.visible = $false 
$Workbook = $Excel.Workbooks.Open("\\Path\Logs\log1.xlsm")
$Worksheet = $Workbook.Worksheets.Item("Payer")

#Gets the number from the last row on the spread sheet 
[int]$lastRowvalue = ($WorkSheet.UsedRange.rows.count + 1) - 1
$lastrow = $lastRowvalue + 1

#Writes name to lastrow column 1
$Worksheet.Cells.Item($lastrow,1) = $FileLine.Split("\")[6]

#Writes Date to lastrow column 2
$Worksheet.Cells.Item($lastrow,2) = $FileDateLine.Split()[8]

#Writes Document count to lastrow column 3
$Worksheet.Cells.Item($lastrow,3) = $FileDocCountLine.Split()[9]


$Excel.DisplayAlerts = $FALSE
$Workbook.Save()
$Workbook.close($true)
$Excel.Quit()
Stop-Process -n Excel
```

Comment: I would make your Excel object, and open the file first, then do a `ForEach` loop to update the workbook for each report, then after the loop save and close the workbook. It could be as simple as `ForEach($Report in (Get-ChildItem \\Path\Report\*.ctx)){`

Answer (score 0):

Code below is not tested but should give you a good start

```
$folder = '\Path\Report\'

$files = Get-ChildItem \\Path\Report\*.ctx

#Open Excel and parse each variable into specific cells
$Excel = New-Object -comobject Excel.Application
$Excel.visible = $false 
$Workbook = $Excel.Workbooks.Open("\\Path\Logs\log1.xlsm")
$Worksheet = $Workbook.Worksheets.Item("Payer")

#Gets the number from the last row on the spread sheet 
[int]$lastRowvalue = ($WorkSheet.UsedRange.rows.count + 1) - 1
$lastrow = $lastRowvalue + 1

foreach($file in $files)
{
   
   
   $data = Get-Content $file
   #Get Data
   #Gets the line with the Date
   $FileDateLine = $data | Select-Object -Index (10)  #starts at zero 

   #Gets the line with the Name
   $FileLine = $data | Select-Object -Index (15)  #starts at zero 

   #Gets the line with the count
   $FileDocCountLine = $data | Select-Object -Index (16)  #starts at zero 

   #Writes name to lastrow column 1
   $Worksheet.Cells.Item($lastrow,1) = $FileLine.Split("\")[6]

   #Writes Date to lastrow column 2
   $Worksheet.Cells.Item($lastrow,2) = $FileDateLine.Split()[8]

   #Writes Document count to lastrow column 3
   $Worksheet.Cells.Item($lastrow,3) = $FileDocCountLine.Split()[9]

   $lastrow++
}

$Excel.DisplayAlerts = $FALSE
$Workbook.Save()
$Workbook.close($true)
$Excel.Quit()
Stop-Process -n Excel
```